# jQuery Mobile: Desktop Browser Compatibility Issue <input type='date'>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, safari

I've been scouring the internet looking for a solution to my problem. I've developed a web-app that's going to be used by both desktop & touchscreen mobile devices, so jQuery Mobile was my framework of choice.

Unfortunately, it appears that the datepicker (input type="date") doesn't show up in Safari on my Macbook laptop. There are a lot of date fields in the app, so this it's really important that this shows.

From jQuery Mobile's documentation (I'm using the latest v1.4), they claim everything works fine for Safari.

Does anybody have input on this, and possibly a solution? I do anticipate a fair number of Macbook users like me.

Thanks so much, always appreciate your input :)

Cheers - - Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Safari provides date-formatted text fields, but no real calendar widget. You need extra picker for some browsers. Maybe do it for all browsers:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 
<script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
```

Prevent showing the native native datepicker:

```
<script>
  //reset type=date inputs to text
  $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
  });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had no problems using the JQM Date box over at http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/ in my jQuery Mobile projects rather than relying on the inbuilt functionality. Worked fine for me on desktops and on Android and iOS devices. You might want to give that a shot.